# C# Transparent back color for richtext

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a form that I want to use with background, when I'm loading the background all my labels and richtexts still have as backcolor "Control", when I choose "Transparent" for the labels it's working, but when I choose it for the richtexts I', getting the error: "Control does not support transparent background colors."

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

NO you can't?

set TransparencyKey of window to control background color
setting this property will make this color transparent on whole window

use two windows overlapping each other one with background and another with your controls with transparency key